# Check if value is bigger or equal to array value

Tags: php, arrays

I've created two array's:

Name array one: `from`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(2) "25" }
```

Name array two: `until`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "23" [1]=> string(2) "31" }
```

Now I want the php script to compare if the value $i (which is starting with a for-loop at `1` and ends by `28, 30 or 31`, depending on the days of the month) is bigger or equal to `from` and smaller of equal to `until`.

But how can I compare the values?

I know i can do this:

```
if($i >= $from[0] && $i <= $untill[0]) {
    echo 'found';
}
else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

But I don't know how big the array will be, it can contain 1 item or 31 or more.

Comment: Do you want to compare each value from `from` with each element from `until` ? I am not sure what you really want

Comment: Could you also post the problem you’re trying to solve? This sounds like an http://xyproblem.info/ and there might be a better way to solve what you’re trying to do.

Comment: I have gotten confused. I could not able to know what is exactly you need to compare.

Comment: I am trying to display a calendar and color the days where someone did a request for a day off.

I want to compare $I (the number of the day)  with the values in $from and $until (daynumbers of employees who asked for a day off)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confuse but i think that i got it, to know how big the array will be, you can use [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), as example, the following code will return only one `found` as only the `6` in the `$until` array will match our `if` requirements, just note that the `$until` array need to be equal or bigger than the `$from` array or we'll get indexes that doesn't actually exist(we can check in the code if it exists too).

```
$from = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$until = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($until); $i++) {
  if($i >= $from[$i] and $i <= $until[$i]) {
    echo 'found';
  }
}
```

In your code you was checking for `$from[0]` and `$untill[0]`, the first value in these arrays, the above code will check for `$from[0]`, `$from[1]`... until we match the `$until` count, the same for `$until`. If then you wanna compare **each** value from `$from` and `$until` then you can do another loop(or one for each array) inside it using the same **count** logic to know how many times you'll need to loop, that is what i think that you was looking for. [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) can be used to do that too, you could get the value or count the index yourself.